# How to populate several select with a generic function (AngularJS)?

Tags: json, angularjs, select, ng-options, ng-init

I'm currently working on this code:

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-init="agreementTypes = initAgreementTypes('ManageMission/GetDescriptions/?type=AgreementTypes')"
        ng-model="mission.AgreementType"
        ng-options="at.Content for at in agreementTypes"></select>
 <select class="form-control"
         ng-init="agreementStatus = initAgreementStatus('ManageMission/GetDescriptions/?type=AgreementStatus')"
         ng-model="mission.AgreementStatus"
         ng-options="as.Content for as in agreementStatus"></select>
```

```
$scope.initAgreementStatus = function (url) {
    $http.get(url).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.agreementStatus = data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("data: " + data);
            console.log("status: " + status);
            console.log("headers: " + headers);
            console.log("config: " + config);
        });
};

$scope.initAgreementTypes = function (url) {
    $http.get(url).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.agreementTypes = data;
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("data: " + data);
            console.log("status: " + status);
            console.log("headers: " + headers);
            console.log("config: " + config);
        });
};
```

This code works, but it's quite ugly. I would like to merge the two functions but I don't know the best way to do it. I've already read some articles about promise. Please keep in mind that I would like to keep URLs in the HTML part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your `$scope` attributes like on any other `Object` using brackets:
`$scope['agreementTypes']`

This way, you can add the name of the attribute, the response should be assigned to:

```
$scope.initDescriptions = function (target, url) {
  $http.get(url)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope[target] = data;
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log("data: " + data);
      console.log("status: " + status);
      console.log("headers: " + headers);
      console.log("config: " + config);
    });
};
```

In your markup, apply the following changes:

```
ng-init="initDescriptions('agreementTypes', 'ManageMission/GetDescriptions/?type=AgreementTypes')"
```